# Serverless Stuck Unable to Create Domain

Tags: aws-serverless

I have a Lambda service that was created with Serverless. I recently upgraded to Serverless 3. (3.22.0 specifically.) I'm also using serverless-offline 8.8.1 and serverless-domain-manager 4.2.3.

It seems to be "stuck" in a state where the domain cannot be deleted or re-created.

After the upgrade, publishing to my prod stage would fail with:

```
Serverless Domain Manager: Info: api-prod.example.com:  Found apiId: pnedwg0m9b
Serverless Domain Manager: Error: api-prod.example.com:  ConflictException: Base path already exists for this domain name
Serverless Domain Manager: Error: api-prod.example.com:  Error: Error: api-prod.example.com: Unable to create basepath mapping.

...

Error: Error: Unable to setup base domain mappings for api-prod.example.com
```

The domain settings in serverless.yml look like this:

```
custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: api-${opt:stage, 'dev'}.example.com
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}
    createRoute53Record: true
```

After searching online, I thought the issue might be that the domain was created with an older version of serverless, so I manually deleted it in the Route53 section of the AWS console, then waited overnight. It doesn't appear in the console now.

I tried to re-create it by doing **both**:

Having createRoute53Record: true in the serverless.yml and running:

```
SLS_DEBUG=* serverless deploy --verbose --stage prod
```

This gives the same "unable to setup base domain mapping..." error as before.

**... and also manually creating it:**

```
SLS_DEBUG=* serverless create_domain --verbose --stage prod
```

That just gives the following error, despite the fact that the domain is **not** visible in the AWS console:

```
Custom domain api-prod.example.com already exists.
```

If I try to delete it via serverless, it also throws an error:

```
SLS_DEBUG=* serverless delete_domain --verbose --stage prod

Serverless Domain Manager: Error: api-prod.example.com:  InvalidChangeBatch: [Tried to delete resource record set [name='api-prod.example.com.', type='A'] but it was not found, Tried to delete resource record set [name='api-prod.example.com.', type='AAAA'] but it was not found]
Serverless Domain Manager: Error: api-prod.example.com:  Error: Error: Failed to DELETE A Alias for api-prod.example.com
```

Some other notes:

- The "development" stage doesn't result in any errors when deploying. (I created the domain with the create_domain command, but even with createRoute53Record:true, it deploys without error.)
- I've tried bumping **serverless-domain-manager** to 6.1, but that didn't help.
- The api-prod.example.com is not present in neither Route53 nor in API Gateway>Custom domain names.
- Not sure if it's relevant but this same API was exposed by **both** api-prod.example.com **and** api.example.com. I'm not sure how the api.example.com one was created.